# Can the ampersand command be aliased with newcommand without issue?

Tags: xml, ampersand

In order to facilitate authoring LaTeX fragments within XML (where `<`, `>`, and `&` are reserved characters), the [PreTeXt](https://pretextbook.org/) specification allows for the use of `\lt`, `\gt`, and `\amp` within math elements, implemented as `\newcommand{\lt}{<}`, `\newcommand{\gt}{>}`, `\newcommand{\amp}{&}` in LaTeX builds.

My naive question is whether `\newcommand{\amp}{&}` is sufficient to perfectly replicate the behavior of an actual `&` in source. It seems to work in practice, but I'm (perhaps unnecessarily) concerned of there being some obscure edge case.

Answer (score 2):

Especially in a pretext document that is encouraging well structured markup, the definitions are probably safe enough, but `\amp` does lose some of the magic alignment properties of `&`.   A definition using `\let` would be closer, although if you compare the results below if you uncomment the marked lines, you may decide you prefer `\amp` to `&` in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\amp{&}
\let\ampb&



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}  
% aaa \iffalse & b\fi & c \\ % unrecoverable mess of errors
ccc & ddd
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{cc}  
aaa \iffalse\amp b\fi & c \\ % no error
ccc & ddd
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{cc}  
% aaa \iffalse\ampb b\fi & c \\ % unrecoverable mess of errors
ccc & ddd
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```